# Can't get basic HTTP Post to work in Salesforce Apex Callout

Tags: salesforce, apex

This is pretty basic. Based on what I've read, this should work. I have a more complex version of this as well.

The To parameter listed below is a List of strings. From and Body are strings.

```
Http http = new Http();
          HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
          request.setEndpoint('https://api.testdomain.com/batchemail');
          request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);   
          request.setMethod('POST');
          request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
          request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
          // Set the body as a JSON object
          request.setBody('{"To": ["to@email.com"]}');
          request.setBody('{"From": "from@email.com"}');
          request.setBody('{"Body": "Test message"}');
          HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

Here is an example of the JSON that the API accepts.

```
{
    "to": ["to@email.com"],
    "from": "from@email.com",
    "body": "Test message"
}
```

The endpoint has been added in Remote Site Settings.

Any idea why this isn't working? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1** (this works)

```
request.setBody('{"To": ["to@email.com"], "From": "from@email.com", "Body": "Test message." }');
```

**UPDATE 2** (this works too)

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
          // Write data to the JSON string.
          gen.writeStartObject();
          gen.writeObjectField('to', emailList);
          gen.writeStringField('from', 'from@email.com');
          gen.writeStringField('body', message);
          gen.writeEndObject();

          // Get the JSON string.
          String pretty = gen.getAsString();

          request.setBody(pretty);
```

**Update 3** (this also works)

Gareth Jordan's Solution works as well.

Comment: whats not working? your multiple calls to setBody are overwriting each other, call it once with the entire payload.

Comment: @superfell Thanks for the help! This is now working. request.setBody('{"To": ["to@email.com"], "From": "from@email.com", "Body": "Test message." }'); Now, I'm trying to insert the actual data into setBody and I'm having issues with the List of To email addresses. Here is what I have tried. request.setBody('{"To": "' + emailList + '", "From": "from@email.com", "Body": "' + message + '" }'); Here is how I'm creating the email list. List<String> emailList = new List<String>(); emailList.Add(email); Thanks again!

Comment: Here is what the API documentation says. To string [] (required)

Comment: you should use the json encoder rather than trying to build it yourself as strings.

Comment: @superfell Please see Update 1. This is not working, either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, call `setBody` once, your 3 calls to `setBody` are just overwriting each other.

for the json generator part, you are double encoding, the variable `pretty` contains the valid generated json, no need to call `json.serialize` it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a simple class (or inner class) for your body and use JSON.serialize(payload).  It makes it cleaner and clearer.

```
class Payload{
    String[] to;
    String sender;
    String body;

     public Payload(String[] recipients, String sender, String message){
        this.to = recipients;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.body = message;
    }
}
```

Then your code would be

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setEndpoint('https://api.testdomain.com/batchemail');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);   
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
Payload body = new Payload(emailList, 'from@email.com','Test Message'); 
request.setBody(JSON.serialize(body).replace('"sender"','"from"'));
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I'm getting this error. Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'from'. at line 169 column 12 For now, I've just commented out 'from' because it's not required. Is 'from" a restricted word?

Comment: Yes from is a reserved word.  One option would be to change the variable and do a string replace to "from"